# Get yesterday date from android

Tags: android, date

```
  Date now = new Date();
String JobReceivedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);
```

By this I can get today's date. How can I date yesterday date??? I want that to be in string and in the same format.
Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); //your formatted date here
```

You will get the day before always !

Answer (score 14):

try this:

```
private String getYesterdayDateString() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);    
        return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I mostly use this

```
Date mydate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String yestr = dateFormat.format(mydate);
```

Now you can get date from "yestr"

Similarly for Tomorrow's date you can change first line like this (just change negative sign to positive)

```
Date mydate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct because System.currentTimeMillis() is universal and you don't know from the local timezone's perspective what was the date yesterday by using current millies